# How can i open binary files (exe) in "Delphi" , like Visual basic?

Tags: delphi, file, binary, exe

in visual basic i can open a binary(exe) file with below way :

```
Strx$ = Space(FileLen(FileName))
Open FileName For Binary As #1
  Get #1, , Strx$
Close
```

in this way i can read all of binary file characters and read file content like this format :

[image]
<sub>(source: [iranblog.com](http://up.iranblog.com/Files/4b97136a8452414b97b1.png))</sub>

and the question is how can i open a binary(exe) file in delphi with a string format(Like image) and not 0,1(binary) format ?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Maybe we can suggest something better, because opening a binary file as text will most likely solve nothing.

Comment: A more common way to do this would be to use a hex viewer/editor component rather than just dumping stuff to the screen which is not readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EXE files contain embedded NULL (#0) Characters.   You may have problems using Strings as typically NULL is found at the end of the string.   Some routines will stop working with a string once the NULL is encountered.

Having said that the following would get the contents of a file into a string.

```
function GetFileIntoString(FileName : String) : String;
var
 SS : TStringStream;
begin
  SS := TStringStream.Create('');   
  try
    SS.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    result := SS.DataString;
  finally
    SS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: memory leak -- you should use try/finally and .free your stringStream

Comment: does it work with Delphi 2009 and higher too? (thinking of Unicode and default character encodings ...)

Comment: Leak Fixed.   In Delphi 2009 the string will be Unicode, and prior it will be Ansi.   Both will load the file into the string.

Comment: See https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=31135&tstart=42 - in Delphi 2009+ TStringStream is a stream of bytes (not a stream of characters), which is fine, but accessing the DataString will process the raw bytes through the TEncoding class, which is not known in this code example.

Comment: @mjustin is right.  In D2009+, accessing the DataString will corrupt the bytes, unless you assign an 8-bit clean TEncoding object to the stream.  Better to use TMemoryStream instead.  Even better, use a memory mapping instead, then you do not have to read the file bytes into a separate memory block at all.

Comment: Why not use Byte size AnsiString or TBytes?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good resources with examples.

- [Create your own Database using Delphi's "File Of" Typed Files
  : Understanding Typed Files](http://delphi.about.com/od/fileio/a/fileof_delphi.htm).
- [Acessing Files With Unknown Structure: Direct Access to Files Regardless of Type and Structuring](http://delphi.about.com/od/fileio/a/untypedfiles.htm).